# How to access JS method in rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-api

I am developing rails app using google maps api.
I want to send the json object created by JS function.
how can I access JS method in controller..

Comment: You need to explain more and provide some context.

Comment: I am developing mobile application with rails as back-end...
i get request from mobile app and wanted to respond in JSON format which will be calculated by JS method as I am using Google map API

Comment: Sounds like you'll need to use [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: If you know what you are doing you can use something like the ruby rhino to execute JS from Ruby. What JS method do you want to call from your controller?